# Run webpack with npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install

I try to use npm scripts but have a few error
npm run server

```
> emergency-webclient@1.0.0 server C:\Work\emergency-webclient\src\src\main\webapp\public
> webpack-dev-server

module.js:440
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Work\emergency-webclient\src\src\main\webapp\public\*'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:159:18)
    at node.js:444:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Illorian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server"
```

Maybe exists more easy way of starting script?
Before it I have used gulp

Webpack and Webpack-dev-server were installed as global.

```
$ node -v
v6.0.0

$ npm -v
3.8.7
```

package.json

```
{
    "dependencies"   : {
        "angular2"        : "latest",
        "rxjs"            : "latest",
        "core-js"         : "^2.3.0",
        "zone.js"         : "~0.6.12",
        "es6-shim"        : "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        //some deps
        "webpack"                    : "^1.13.0",
        "webpack-dev-server"         : "^1.14.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that if you want you can use webpack with gulp.

Comment: @JoakimEricsson I know, but I want to understand how to use scripts

Comment: Can you add your **webpack-dev-server** related bits? It's hard to say anything concrete based on the current information alone.

Comment: @bebraw I can't launch any script. It doen't matter webpack or something else...

Comment: Ok. It could be something path related. Maybe you can simplify the setup somehow. As I said, there's not a lot of information to work with.

Comment: @bebraw What can I do if they are already install globally?

Comment: Ah, global install... It's probably a better idea to keep those as direct development dependencies of your project and then do `npm run build` and so on. I didn't spot this as there wasn't enough info.

Comment: @bebraw I've updated description. There are already in devDependencies.

Comment: @bebraw I fount http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/developing_with_webpack/#adding-a-build-shortcut

But I've already have a webpack folder

Comment: @Illorian Can you push a sample project somewhere? Easier to tell what's going on.

Comment: @bebraw https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-KvhNKMGidOd19UMWpaLWxWSFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `npm run server` leads to `ERROR in ./project/app/boot.ts
(3,8): error TS2656: Exported external package typings file '/Users/juhovepsalainen/Projects/tmp/so/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts' is not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package definition.` on os x (Node 5, npm 3). Is that expected?

Comment: @bebraw yes. It's a library bag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111141/discussion-between-bebraw-and-illorian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows has helped with this problem

Comment: Is this answer for real?

Comment: @ChrisHermut yes. Reinstalling node and all packages doesn't help me. On mac I have no problems with this